# Make variable available to other callbacks

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a variable available to the other callback functions :

```
$(function(){
    $("#home_sec_2 img").attr("id", function (arr) {
        return arr;
    });
    $('#home_sec_2').on('mouseover','img',function(){
        position = $(this).position().left;
        var $ll = $(this).prev();
        console.log($ll);
        /* $ll.css({left: position}); */
        $ll.css({left:position});

        $ll.addClass('shown');
        $ll.stop().slideToggle('slow');
        var $this = $ll;
        console.log(position);
        var pp = $ll.position();
        console.log(pp);
    }),     
    $('#home_sec_2').on('mouseleave','img',function(){
        /* $ll = $(this).attr('id');     */
        **var $img = $(this).prev()**
        $img.slideToggle('slow');
         console.log($img);
    })
});
```

The `$img` variable is on I want to make available how do I access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make a global variable then ?

```
<script>
 var your_var;
  $('#home_sec_2').on('mouseover','img',function(){
    your_var = 'some initialization';
  });
  $('#home_sec_2').on('mouseleave','img',function(){
    alert(your_var);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the scope of `$img` so it's outside of that binding and is just below your document ready. e.g.

```
$(function(){
  // declare $img scope here
  var $img;

  /*
    other code
    ...
    if ($img) { ... }
    ...
  */

  $('#home_sec_2').on('mouseleave','img',function(){
    // assign it here
    $img = $(this).prev();
  });
});
```

Just make sure to test `if($img)` before you use it anywhere else, or set a default value.

Comment: I want to assign the variable in the mouseover function and use it in the mouseleave.. But i still cant get it to work